# Do I need to be on the latest version of macOS for Apple Store repair?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

My late 2012 retina MacBook Pro needs a new battery installed. If I take it to the Apple Store for repair, will they require me to install the newest supported macOS version before they will replace my battery? I currently have 10.14 Mojave installed because I like iTunes and I do not want to update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they should not require you to update.

However, even if they do (such as if they damage the machine and have to wipe it for some unforeseen reason) a backup can still be restored to Mojave.

There is no restriction to prevent you from restoring your computer to an earlier version, so long as it is compatible with that version.

Comment: Bearing in mind that security updates for Mojave have either already ended, or are about to.